# Select *FROM table two and count(coulmn_name) FROM table one

Tags: mysql, sql

How can i select * FROM table two and count(t_type) FROM table one WHERE species in table one and two are equal

Table one = trees

```
id | t_type
~~~~~~~~~~~~
1  | Tree one 
2  | Tree two
3  | Tree Three 
4  | Tree Four 
5  | Tree one
```

Table two = requests

```
id | req_species
~~~~~~~~~~~~
1  | Tree one 
2  | Tree two 
3  | Tree one 
4  | Tree two
```

The returned table will have same number of rows as of table two (requests), in this case 4 rows.

Expected Output

```
species | Qunatity
~~~~~~~~~~~~
Tree one | 2
Tree two | 1
Tree one | 2
Tree two | 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method uses a correlated subquery:

```
select r.species,
       (select count(*) from trees t where t.species = r.species) as quantity
from requests r;
```

Comment: Is it possible to SELECT * FROM r?

Comment: @SaiKiranVeeraneni . . . Of course.  Just say `r.*` instead of `r.species`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(T1.t_type) AS QUALITY,T1.t_type
FROM TABLE_1 AS T1  WHERE T1.t_type IN 
     (SELECT T2.req_species FROM TABLE_2 AS T2)

GROUP BY T1.t_type
```